# Delphi Indy SRP

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy, single-responsibility-principle

Goodmorning everyone.

I'm trying to implement SRP in Delphi.
Looking through sources Indy 10 I found the following code:

```
  {$EXTERNALSYM SRP_user_pwd}
  SRP_user_pwd = record
      id  : PIdAnsiChar;
    s : PBIGNUM;
    v : PBIGNUM;
      g : PBIGNUM;
      N : PBIGNUM;
    info : PIdAnsiChar;
  end;
  {$EXTERNALSYM PSRP_user_pwd}
  PSRP_user_pwd = ^SRP_user_pwd;
```

I assume that you have already implemented the protocol SRP, but can not find anything that can help me to use it directly.

At this point I'm trying to translate what I found at this link: https://github.com/cocagne/csrp/blob/master/srp.c.

So I'm trying to import the functions that I need from the library openssl like this:

```
initialization

  LoadOpenSSLLibrary;

  @BN_num_bytes:= GetProcAddress( GetCryptLibHandle, PChar( 'BN_num_bytes' ) );
  @BN_bn2bin:= GetProcAddress( GetCryptLibHandle, PChar( 'BN_bn2bin' ) );
  @BN_bin2bn:= GetProcAddress( GetCryptLibHandle, PChar( 'BN_bin2bn' ) );
  @SHA512 := GetProcAddress( GetCryptLibHandle, PChar( 'SHA512' ) );
  @BN_CTX_new := GetProcAddress( GetCryptLibHandle, PChar( 'BN_CTX_new' ) );
  @BN_rand := GetProcAddress( GetCryptLibHandle, PChar( 'BN_rand' ) );
  @BN_mod_exp := GetProcAddress( GetCryptLibHandle, PChar( 'BN_mod_exp' ) );
  @BN_CTX_free := GetProcAddress( GetCryptLibHandle, PChar( 'BN_CTX_free' ) );
```

I find the entry for each of these but not for the function BN_num_bytes.

In the documentation openssl, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BN_num_bytes.html, function it exists, so obviously I'm doing something wrong.

If someone has already implemented the SRP in Delphi, I would be very grateful for any suggestions or maybe the code :D.
Otherwise suggestions of how to use Indy that I have not found.
Or even like that I can call this function, and continuous hard work to personally wrapper for Delphi with all the bugs that i can include :(.

Thanks all.

Comment: found an implementation [here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/54477-secure-remote-password-protocol.html) (site is in German, you'll need  a translator...)

Comment: Thanks, but I needed to implement it in my tcp applications for Android, and I cant obviously use dll.

Comment: Indy DOES NOT support SRP at this time.  Despite what you see in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` unit, Indy does not use everything in it.